# Which side is "up" on this nylon nut?

Tags: fasteners

I have this nylon nut, and I wonder which side should contact the material:

[image]

- Is it the wide hex face, because the nut is built like a lock-nut?
- or is it the cylindrical face because it serves as an integrated washer?

Comment: It's the faying surface and yes it works like a washer. The Idea is to manage the torque due to friction so that you get the clamping force you want. If the bolthead has a bigger diameter, he nut will self tighten without having to hold the bolthead.

Comment: @PhilSweet You should make it the answer.

Comment: @PhilSweet Thanks for adding "faying" to my vocabulary. Could you please explain though why one face is better than the other? Why would we be worse off if the nut was flipped?

Comment: I've got a similar question. I'd love to know more about this. Is this a reversible link, if I flip the nut can I turn the screw without backing the nut?